# Google cloud functions contains whole application code unlike aws lambda which contains only function specific code

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-lambda, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was using aws lambda for few projects. In lambda i can package only function specific code so every function has only its own code. and now i am using google cloud functions for my new project. I've deployed few functions but all the functions contains whole application code. It contains code of other functions too which we don't need. Is it how it works in google cloud functions or did i implemented/deployed it wrong way? or it doesn't matter to keep all the code in every function.

Comment: Is it causing you any problems? Is there a more specific example of the problem you can give us?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.